# javascript function giving NULL inside a snowflake function

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a function inside snowflake using Javascript to calculate the string distance However the function is giving me NULL values. I am not able to debug the function.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cat_map_trial4(a string,b string)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
function levenshteinDistance(s1, s2) {
    if (!s1.length) return toString(s2.length);
    if (!s2.length) return toString(s1.length);

    return toString(Math.min(
        levenshteinDistance(s1.substr(1), s2) + 1,
        levenshteinDistance(s2.substr(1), s1) + 1,
        levenshteinDistance(s1.substr(1), s2.substr(1)) + (s1[0] !== s2[0] ? 1 : 0)
    ) + 1);
}
$$


select cat_map_trial4('stackoverflow', 'stack') as dist;
```

Output

```
dist
NULL
```

What is going wrong with Javascript ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of issues in your code

- you define a function, but do not use it, you need to add a call at the end
- you incorrectly use toString, if you insist on strings, use String(value)
- if you use strings, you can't add them with a '+' to add their numeric values...
- you have an unnecessary +1 at the end
- you use a very slow implementation of this algorithm, you should be using something faster, read up on [various ways to compute it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance)

Here's a corrected version (still slow, but works):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cat_map_trial4(a string,b string)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
function levenshteinDistance(s1, s2) {
    if (!s1.length) return s2.length;
    if (!s2.length) return s1.length;
    return Math.min(
        levenshteinDistance(s1.substr(1), s2) + 1,
        levenshteinDistance(s2.substr(1), s1) + 1,
        levenshteinDistance(s1.substr(1), s2.substr(1)) + (s1[0] !== s2[0] ? 1 : 0)
    );
}
return levenshteinDistance(A, B);
$$;
```

But the biggest problem with your code is that it's **completely unnecessary**, as Snowflake, being as awesome as it is, provides a built-in, fast [`EDITDISTANCE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/editdistance.html) function :)